# ionic 2 multiple selection with select all Check Box

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want provided select option with **ion-select**. I have manually added select all option at first position, when I select all view is not updated. how can updated view ?

[image]
**.html**

```
<ion-select multiple="true">
      <ion-option (ionSelect)="allClicked()">select all</ion-option>
      <ion-option *ngFor="let item of students ; let i = index" [selected]="item.checked" [value]="item">{{item.studentName}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

**.ts**

```
       allClicked(){
        if(this.isAll){
           console.log(this.isAll)
            this.isAll = false;
            for (let temp of this.students) {
             temp.checked = false;
               }
        }else{
        this.isAll = true;

        for (let temp of this.students) {
           temp.checked = true;
           }
          }
        console.log("all select event ");
        }
```

Comment: are the console logs printing correctly?

Comment: @SurajRao Yes but Model is not updating

Comment: Can you please explain bit more because not getting in question

Comment: you will need to rephrase the question.. you mean toggling select all doesnt update other options?

Comment: @Suraj Rao question updated check

Comment: @PareshGami check question

Comment: ion-select is open in modal right?

Comment: @PareshGami yes

Comment: is the array updated? `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.students))`?

Comment: allClicked() event triggers only when setting the option, and not when you toggle it off.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a very similar problem. inject ChangeDetectorRef and call cdRef.detectChanges()

So code must be like:

```
import {Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef} from 'angular2/core';

export class RecentDetectionComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef // <== added ) {

}



 allClicked(){
   if(this.isAll){
   console.log(this.isAll)
   this.isAll = false;
   for (let temp of this.students) 
   {
   temp.checked = false;
   }
   }else{
   this.isAll = true;
   for (let temp of this.students) {
   temp.checked = true;
   }
   }
   console.log("all select event ");
   this.cdRef.detectChanges(); // <== added
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

one solution is to put all the student in the model for ion-select

```
<ion-select multiple="true" [(ngModel)]="selectStudents">
      <ion-option (ionSelect)="allClicked()">select all</ion-option>
      <ion-option *ngFor="let item of students ; let i = index" [selected]="item.checked" [value]="item">{{item.studentName}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

**ts.**

```
selectStudents:[];
function allClicked(){
    selectStudents=[];
    students.filter((data)=>{
       this.selectStudents.push(data.studentName);
    });
}
```

I am assuming that students is a array of students.